# cygwin error saying Config.pm not found and cannot be found

Tags: cygwin, dmake

I am firing a command on cygwin `dmake`

it is giving error as

```
$ dmake
dmake.exe:  Error: -- `\usr\lib\perl5\5.14\x86_64-cygwin-threads\Config.pm' not found, and      can't be made
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a needed PERL library.  Do you have PERL installed?  You could also try reinstalling PERL using cygwin.  I use cygwin on a 64 bit machine and I have that library under the following directory /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/Config.pm?

Comment: I have PERL installed on my system. I have installed perl before installing cygwin

Comment: You need to install PERL using cygwin since it is looking for that one.  Do you have the path /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 on your machine?

Comment: /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 path exists.  what to do now as it does not have other sub directories

Comment: Got it. It is searching for `i686-cygwin-threads-64int`. But in my system it is `/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads`. How to change the path

Comment: Looks like the dmake is looking for a 32 bit version of PERL.  Per the Cygwin site Cygwin has a 32 and a 64 bit installer which one did you use? The most recent version of the Cygwin DLL is 1.7.28. Install it by running setup-x86.exe (32-bit installation) or setup-x86_64.exe (64-bit installation).